# Current tab is not showing in "Choose what to share alert" in chrome extention MV3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, screen-recording

Click here to see Screenshot

[image: 1]
I am working on chrome extenton for screen recording and when I triggered the `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` the alert openend as in screenshot but the current tab is missing in this.
My manifest.json file code is here

```
{
  "name": "web-vcr",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Save Videos",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "desktopCapture", "downloads", "scripting", "activeTab"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js"
  },
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["*://*/*"],
     "css": ["css/styles.css", "css/injected-script.css"],
     "js": [
       "js/video-tools.js",
       "js/content-script.js",
       "js/inject-script.js"
      ]
   }
  ],
  "action" : {
    "default_icon": "img/icon-32.png",
    "default_popup": "html/popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "256": "img/icon.png",
    "32": "img/icon-32.png"
  }
}
```

**Is any other method to get all tabs including current tab for recording or I missed something?**

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roIVo.png)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

let recorder;
var audioRecord;
let chunks = [];

const App = () => {
  const [attachment, setAttachment] = useState("");

   const onScreen = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then((stream) => {
    if (!MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported("audio/webm"))
    return alert("Browser not supported");
    audioRecord = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
    mimeType: "audio/webm",
    });
    navigator.mediaDevices
    .getDisplayMedia({
      video: true,
      preferCurrentTab: true,
    })
    .then((screenStream) => {
      let combinedStream = new MediaStream([
        ...screenStream.getTracks(),
        ...stream.getTracks(),
      ]);
      recorder = new MediaRecorder(combinedStream);
      recorder.start();
      recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        chunks.push(event.data);
      };
      })
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
      });
      };

      function downloadVideo() {
       console.log("download");
       if (recorder && recorder.state !== "inactive") {
       recorder.stop();
       recorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
       audioRecord.stop();
       audioRecord.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
       recorder.stop();
       recorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
       recorder.onstop = (videoBlob) => {
       let file = new File(chunks, `video.mp4`, {
        type: "video/mp4",
        });
       setAttachment(file);
       chunks = [];
       let url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
       console.log(file, "file");
        };
       recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
       chunks.push(event.data);
        };
        }
       }

       return (
       <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={onScreen}>Start</button>
        <button onClick={downloadVideo}>download</button>
      </div>
       </>
        );
         };

        export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: preferCurrentTab props is so powerful

Comment: Throwing error: 
`Argument of type '{ video: true; preferCurrentTab: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DisplayMediaStreamOptions'.`

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we are using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` in content-script but when we use this in our service worker then it shows all tabs as `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` can't be use directly in the service worker in chrome manifest_version 3 so we need to use it in [offscreen](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).